# Is it possible to add undetected Github commits to the "contributions" pane retroactively?

Tags: git, github

I didn't realize I needed to add my email address to `.gitconfig` for Github to detect commits as "contributions," resulting in several months of commits failing to show up in the "contributions" pane. Is it possible to add these commits as contributions retroactively? Perhaps I can change the email address/name of the "committer" for each of my past commits, and the "contributions" pane will update itself? How can I accomplish this with `git`?

Edit: To clarify, I am the only contributor for the relevant repositories. I just use Github as a nice way to backup my files, sync them to different workstations, and keep track of my changes.

Comment: Are you the only contributor? Changing past commits means rewriting the entirety of history, so it usually inconveniences any other people working on a project. If your past commits were made with an e-mail address you don’t prefer instead of an outright wrong one, you can also tell GitHub to associate that address with your account. Apart from those, I don’t know of any solutions.

Comment: Yep, I am; clarified that in the question.

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info/, then.

Comment: Thanks -- wasn't sure if those contribution tiles were continually updated to reflect rebases/repository history changes; I guess that was the unique part of my question. Anyone arriving here should see the referenced thread/link.